# VIM jump to the next logical block in a program

Tags: vim, plugins

Is there a functionality inside VIM or a VIM plugin that lets a user jump to the next blank line ("logical block" inside a program)?

Example:

```
// cursor is originally here
-> means the next location of jump
#include<stdio.h>
->
main()
{
   -> 
   int n;
   ->
   printf("Enter an integer\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   ->
   if ( n & 1 == 1 )
      printf("Odd\n");
   else
      printf("Even\n");
   ->
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course there is! `:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very simple is to use the paragraph motion with `}` to jump forward and `{` to jump backwards.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. } jumps to line before main, then to end of a program. The way I understand { or } jumps to next paragraph - and those "logical blocks" are not paragraphs.

Comment: I take it back. I use a plugin for my IDE and it doesn't do it, but vim inside terminal does exactly the way you described. Sorry.